# Can we always find two curves intersecting in a given set of points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and $\{P_1, \dots, P_k\}\subseteq\mathbb{P}_K^2$. Can we always find two algebraic curves $F$ and $G$, i.e. homogeneous polynomials $F, G\in K[X, Y, Z]$, such that $V(F, G)=\{P_1, \dots, P_k\}$?

---

This problem was given to me as a homework problem for $K=\mathbb{R}$, where the answer is obviously yes: If $P_i=(x_i:y_i:z_i)$, where we can WLOG assume that $z_i\neq 0$ for all $i$ after a suitable coordinate transformation, then just take
$$
F = G = \prod_{i=1}^k ((X-x_i)^2+(Y-y_i)^2),
$$
which obviously yields $V(F) = V(G) = \{P_1, \dots, P_k\}$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

A similar construction can be used to show that we can always find curves $F$ and $G$ as desired if $K$ is *not* algebraically closed (just take some polynomial in $X$ without a root in $K$ and homogenise to get a homogeneous polynomial in $K[X, Y]$; the curve it defines will only have $(0:0:1)$ as a point).

But what if $K$ is algebraically closed? I tried using Riemann-Roch, but did not succeed as one would have to control the infinitely many points in $\mathbb{P}_K^2\setminus\{P_1, \dots, P_k\}$, which seems impossible with this approach.

Comment: Maybe the affine version of the question can help somehow:  [Any finite algebraic subset of $\mathbb A^2_k$ can be determined by 2 equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585268/any-finite-algebraic-subset-of-mathbb-a2-k-can-be-determined-by-2-equations)

Comment: Well, the original problem was for $\mathbb{A}_K^2$ instead of $\mathbb{P}_K^2$ so ... however, I thought maybe considering projective space would make things nicer

Comment: Are you requiring that each point occurs with multiplicity one? If not, then taking $k$ prime and $k$ points not lying on a line yields a counterexample.

Comment: I am not requiring $\mu_{P_i}(F, G)=1$, merely that these are the only intersection points.

Comment: Are you assuming in the non-algebraically closed field case, the points are rational over the field? If the points are rational ( in particular field is algebraically closed) the answer is yes. If the points are not rational over the base field, this is an open question due to Gennady Lyubeznik.

Comment: Yes, the points are rational, everything is taking place solely in $K$.